# How can I get modal dialog to pop up once per session using HTML SCRIPT Tag only?

Tags: javascript, html, plsql

How can I get this modal dialog to pop up once per browser session? Every time I refresh the homepage it pops up. I only want it to pop up once per browser session. I have to include this in the HTML script tags, there is no separate JS file. This is all inside of a PLSQL procedure using the "htp.print" command.

```
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal message</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
   $( function ModalPopup() {
     $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
       modal: true,
       width: 500,
       buttons: {
         OK: function ModalPopup() {
           $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
       }
     });
   } );
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="dialog-message" title="Important Message">
    <p><b>This is Protected system.</b><br><br>
      <b>This system is for authorized users only.</b><br><br>

 By accessing and using this information system, you acknowledge and consent to the following:<br><br>

 •  You are accessing classified information system (which includes any device attached to this information system) that is provided for authorized use only.<br>  
 •  Unauthorized or improper use of this system and its contents may result in suspension or loss of access privileges, disciplinary action, and/or civil and/or criminal penalties.<br> 

 </p>
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vwh6r5mz/)

Comment: You mention "browser session". Is there a backend that is creating/controlling this session? If so, can you tell us what flavor the backend is and post that code?

Comment: @ControlAltDel while there are definitely better languages for browser session management, the question explicitly states that the desired behavior should be in `script` tags

Comment: @Esdeseserdt1976 The way to fix this is to change the script from the app server and only pop up the dialog when the session is initially set up